# Losing opacity information when saving an animated scatterplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, opacity

Hi all I'm quite new to using python, and am currently running the following code to generate an animated scatterplot for my simulation:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
mpl.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path'] = r'C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe'

'''removed large chunk of code which correctly calculates positions etc'''

duration = 40  # length of movie in seconds

fps = 200  # required frames per second of movie

pixelx = 512  # length of x for resulting movie in pixels

pixely = 512  # length of x for resulting movie in pixels

positionlist2d, positionlist3d, alphas, sizes = movement()  # gets 2D and 3D particle co-ords for each frame in movie duration, alphas are the opacities which range dependant on z co-ord of particle and are visible in plt.show()

px = 1/plt.rcParams['figure.dpi']

fig2d, ax2d = plt.subplots(figsize=(pixelx * px, pixely * px), dpi=72, frameon=False)  # graph size, dpi correct ratio for particle size

plt.margins(x=0, y=0, tight=True)

ax2d.set_axis_off()

scatter2d = ax2d.scatter([], [], s=(pixelx*particle.rad/sim.X)**2, alpha=alphas)  # scatter, particle scale size, edgecolors='black'

ani2d = FuncAnimation(fig2d, update2d, frames=(duration * fps), init_func=initial2d, blit=False, interval=1000/fps,
                      repeat=True)  # update function to create animation of particle using calculated data

ani2d.save('2D.gif', fps=fps)

plt.show()
```

Could anyone advise me as to why I lose the alpha (opacity) data when saving in this format, while it is still visible in plt.show()?

Comment: Question is missing some code
Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: I think that should be all the required code? The alphas are calculated correctly and show in plt.show() just don't show when opened later through the file created by .save

Answer (score 0):

framon = False removes the opacity data and white background from the final image